# How to pass variable in jquery for loop variable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Just getting into JQuery and Asp.net MVC 2 and wanted to know how to pass variables from a loop to a javascript function.

So I have :

```
<% int i = 0; %>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
         <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" onclick="javascript:updatePerson(i);" />
         <input type="text" id='<%= "persons[" + i + "].Name" %>'  name='<%= "persons[" + i + "].Name" %>' value='<%=item.Name %>' />
        </td>

    </tr>

    <% i++; %>
<% } %>
```

Clearly

```
onclick="javascript:updatePerson(i);"
```

is wrong.

How do I pass the variable i into the updatePerson function?

JD

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you taking a different, better approach as right now I see that you are mixing C#, javascript and HTML into the same page which results in what is called horrible tag soup.

So improvement number 1: use editor templates instead of those foreach loops. In your main view instead of writing what you've posted in your question simply:

```
<%= Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

and then define an editor template which will be called automatically for each element in your model collection (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/Person.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<YourApp.Models.Person>" %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Persons", 
            new { id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post, 
            new { @class = "saveform" })) { %>
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <% } %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Notice that the name of the partial is the same as the type name to which it is strongly typed (`Person.ascx`). Also notice the location: `~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates` where `Home` of course is the name of the current controller. It could also be placed in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` if you wanted to reuse it between multiple controllers. And because the editor template is strongly typed to a view model you can use strongly typed helpers such as `Html.TextBoxFor` so that you don't have to manually hardcode names and values of the textboxes and wonder why does the model binder doesn't work correctly.

Improvement number 2: progressively enhance your markup with jquery in a separate javascript file:

```
$(function() {
    $('.saveform').submit(function() {
        // When the form is submitted
        // For example you could call the associated action using AJAX:
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                alert('successfully saved');
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have just started learning ASP.NET MVC2 and JQuery so I really appreciate the help you have provided. I will read more on templates and hopefully start to plug them in.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the current value of `i` in your Javascript expression in the same way you're doing it in the rest of your code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Save"
    onclick="updatePerson(<%= i %>);" />
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic, Omkar got in just before you but I did mark it up :)

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="javascript:updatePerson(<%=i%>);"
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks Omkar, just spent an hour looking and was about to give up.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client side while asp is serverside. In other words:

1. ASP generates html
2. The HTML is sent to browser
3. Your javascript is executed by the browser.

That's why your original code doesn't work. `i` do not exist in the generated html.